# Create a unique constraint with CHECK in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider that there is the following table:

```
create table table_1(
    id                 serial
                       PRIMARY KEY,
    col1               varchar(50),
    col2               varchar(50),
    status             varchar(1)  -- A=active P=pending D=Deleted
);
```

now what I want is to create a unique constraint on (col1,col2) but it should not consider those with status ='D' i.e Consider there is 2 rows in the table:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col1,col2,status) VALUES ('row1', 'row1', 'A');
INSERT INTO table_1(col1,col2,status) VALUES ('row2', 'row2', 'D');
```

Then I should NOT be able to add the following row:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col1,col2,status) VALUES ('row1', 'row1', 'A');
```

But I SHOULD be able to add the following row:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col1,col2,status) VALUES ('row2', 'row2', 'A');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a partial unique index:

```
create unique index id_table1_col1_col2_status on table_1(col1, col2, status)
    where status <> 'D';
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c414/3) is a SQL Fiddle that you can use to see it work.

Comment: Thank you. I just need this: create unique index id_table1_col1_col2 on table_1(col1, col2)
    where status <> 'D';
I did not know we could use WHERE when creating an index.

Comment: How will `status <> 'D'` work if `status is null`? If it's never going to be `null`, then it should be created with the `not null` constraint.